# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

I'm trying to get my activity working, but I keep getting the exception below, any idea of what's happening? Thank you!

(Thank you! and sorry for lack of information, I'm just newbie here and also in Android xD)

**EXCEPTION**

```
 Process: com.generarencuestas.isbcan.generarencuestas, PID: 27050
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
      at com.gestionencuestas.isbcan.gestionencuestas.DraftFragment.onCreateView(DraftFragment.java:59)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18849)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5904)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:607)
      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1238)
      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:672)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18849)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5904)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
      at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18849)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5904)
      at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18849)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5904)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18849)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5904)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18849)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5904)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3073)
      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18849)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1622)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1264)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6944)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
```

**XML**

There's an xml (content_home) where I inflate a CardView (card_survey.xml)

content_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/_2dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/_2dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:numColumns="2"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/noMessages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:visibility="gone">

                <!-- LINE 24 below -->
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/noMessagesIcon"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_empty"
                    android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/noMessagesText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/no_surveys_found"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

card_survey.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/_5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/overlayImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textNameAsset"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/overlayImage"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textNameAsset"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textParticip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textDate"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**CODE**

DraftFragment.class

```
/**
 * Created by n52830 on 20/07/2017.
 */

public class DraftFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private HashMap<String,SurveyDao> surveyList = new HashMap<>();
    private final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private LinearLayout noMessagesView;
    private GridView gridView;
    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(saveInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        surveyList = new HashMap<>();
        sharedpreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PreferencesEnum.PREFERENCES.getCode(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_home, container, false);
        noMessagesView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.noMessages);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        getDrafts();

        return view;
    }

    private void getDrafts(){
        String loggedUser = sharedpreferences.getString(PreferencesEnum.NUMEMPLOYEE.getCode(), "");
        final DatabaseReference usersReference = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.USERS_REFERENCE);
        Query queryAssetQueue = usersReference.orderByChild(FirebaseReferences.NUMEMPLOYEE_REFERENCE).equalTo(loggedUser);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage(this.getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        progressDialog.show();

        queryAssetQueue.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                obtainSurvey(dataSnapshot, view);
                dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                obtainSurvey(dataSnapshot, view);
                dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                obtainSurvey(dataSnapshot, view);
                dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                dismissProgressDialog(progressDialog);
            }
        });
    }

    private void obtainSurvey(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, final View view){
        surveyList = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        UserDao user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDao.class);
        HashMap draftSurveysMap = user.getDrafts();
        Map<String, String> sortedSurveysMapAsc = sortByComparator(draftSurveysMap, true);
        Object[] drafts = sortedSurveysMapAsc.entrySet().toArray();
        if(drafts.length == 0){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            showEmptyState(true);
        }else {
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> surveyEntry : sortedSurveysMapAsc.entrySet()){
                final DatabaseReference surveysReference = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.SURVEY_REFERENCE).child(surveyEntry.getKey());
                surveysReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        SurveyDao survey = snapshot.getValue(SurveyDao.class);
                        if(survey != null){
                            survey.setId(snapshot.getKey());
                            surveyList.put(snapshot.getKey(),survey);
                            GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                            gridView.setAdapter(new SurveyAdapter(view.getContext(), surveyList, (SurveyAdapter.ListItemClickListener) getActivity()));
                            showEmptyState(surveyList.size() == 0);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //do whatever you want here
    }
    public void showEmptyState(boolean empty) {
        if (empty) {
            gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            noMessagesView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            noMessagesView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

SurveyAdapter.class

```
public class SurveyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final List<SurveyDao> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private static ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener; // Reference to item click item listener
    private TabLayout tabLayout;


    public SurveyAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String,SurveyDao> surveys, ListItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnClickListener = listener;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        for (SurveyDao survey : surveys.values()) {
            mItems.add(new SurveyDao(survey.getId(), survey.getName(), survey.getStatus(), survey.getType_id(), survey.getGroup_id(), survey.getEndDate(),
                    survey.getPublishDate(), survey.getParticipation(), survey.getNumParticipation(), survey.getCreated(), survey.getModified(),
                    survey.getUsu_modified(), survey.getUsu_created(), survey.getQuestions()));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public SurveyDao getItem(int i) {

        return mItems.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return mItems.get(i).getType_id();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name, date, participation;

        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_survey, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.overlayImage, v.findViewById(R.id.overlayImage));
            v.setTag(R.id.textNameAsset, v.findViewById(R.id.textNameAsset));
            v.setTag(R.id.textDate, v.findViewById(R.id.textDate));
            v.setTag(R.id.textParticip, v.findViewById(R.id.textParticip));
        }

        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.overlayImage);
        name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.textNameAsset);
        date = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.textDate);
        participation = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.textParticip);

        SurveyDao item = getItem(i);

        int typeSurvey;
        switch (item.getType_id()) {
            case 0:
                typeSurvey = R.drawable.ic_survey;
                break;
            case 1:
                typeSurvey = R.drawable.ic_training;
                break;
            case 2:
                typeSurvey = R.drawable.ic_events;
                break;
            default:
                typeSurvey = R.drawable.ic_blank;
                break;
        }
        picture.setImageResource(typeSurvey);
        name.setText(item.getName());
        date.setText(v.getContext().getString(R.string.date_survey_ends, convertCompleteDate(item.getEndDate())));
        participation.setText(v.getContext().getString(R.string.porc_participation, item.getParticipation().toString()+"%"));

        picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SurveyDao surveyItem = getItem(i);
                mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(surveyItem);
            }
        });
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SurveyDao surveyItem = getItem(i);
                mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(surveyItem);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
    public interface ListItemClickListener {
        void onListItemClick(SurveyDao surveyItem);
    }

public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intentSurvey = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intentSurvey);
    finish();
}
 // more code ...
}
```

**gradle compileSdkVersion:** 24 
**gradle buildToolsVersion:** 25

Comment: Seems to be a problem with `DraftFragment`'s XML. Can you post that?

Comment: Post your XML code

Comment: please check in your xml file line no 24

Comment: post your XML code

Comment: updated! sorry guys! thank you very much !

Comment: Logs error comes from inflating error in your DraftFragment, not your MainActivity. Can you add in question DraftFragment java class and its corresponding layout, instead of MainActivity and content_home.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag and seem's like It works, at least for the crash casuistic. Hope It keeps well-functioning...

Answer (score 1):

This can be also be caused when an `OutOfMemoryError` has been thrown

Comment: Yap ! android:largeHeap="true" fixed it ^^

Answer (score 0):

In your layout.xml there's should be an error in the class name of a view.

If you are using custom View, you should indicate the complete class name with package

```
<com.my.package.ui.MyAwesomeCustomView
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- ... --->
</com.my.package.ui.MyAwesomeCustomView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to predict actual line no #24 but your line `tools:visibility="gone"` seems to have issue.

Change `tools:visibility="gone"`to `android:visibility="gone"`